# How i can change implementation of method of dynamically loaded class in java im using frida

Tags: java, android, security, frida

im using frida , and would like to know how to change the (implementation) of sayHi method if the banana class is loaded dynamically

```
Class banan_dynamically_loaded
{
   Public void   sayHi()
    {
        console.log("hi");
     }

}
```

And i know about reflection and hooking the dexclassloader class and overload the Loadclass method,  but that only allow me to invoke the method sayHi not changing it's implementation

Comment: Some punctuation would have made your question way more readable. Without it is just a very long line of words. Additionally if you already have code it would be wise to post the relevant parts, then it would be easier for other to point you to where it has to be modified and how.

Comment: Done edited the question thanks Robert

Comment: Have you tried to apply the hoking after the class has been loaded?

Comment: I did a  mistake using frida but i learnt how to hook the dexloaderclass and invoke so it was great experience i solved it by starting frida correctly : frida -U -f app-full-name thank you robert